# Need to cut part of a string in shell scripting

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have a string `example.123.ytu.tar.gz`

I want to have `example.123.ytu.tar` how can i get in shell scripting

I tried with

`echo example.123.ytu.tar | cut -d "." -f3`, But it is giving only `tar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `basename` for this.

```
$ basename --suffix ".gz" example.123.ytu.tar.gz
example.123.ytu.tar
```

You can find out more about it via `man basename`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo example.123.ytu.tar.gz | cut -d "." -f1-4
example.123.ytu.tar
```

The `-f` option takes any comma separated list of fields and/or field ranges (with '-'). Eg

```
echo example.123.ytu.tar.gz | cut -d "." -f1,2,3,4
example.123.ytu.tar
```

gives the same output.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear in my question. The exact thing I want is to have a string till *.tar or before ".gz"

Comment: I have edited the answer. But if you look at the previous example you should see how to get the result you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use `grep`

```
echo example.123.ytu.tar | grep -Eo '.*tar'
```

output: `example.123.ytu.tar`

The `-E` option enables extended regular expression mode and the `-o` option makes grep print only the part of the word that matched the regex.